# How do you install pythonbrew when using the Fish Shell?

Tags: macos, python, terminal.app, fish

I use the Fish shell in Mac OS X and I cannot figure out how to install pythonbrew. Is this possible and if so how? What I think I need to figure out is how to convert the following for my .bashrc to the Fish equivalent and place it in my fish.config:

```
[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
```

However, I'm not even sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the following lines into your ~/.config/fish/config.fish file:

```
if test -s ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
    . ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
end
```

However, the bashrc file in ~/.pythonbrew/etc/ is not recognized by the fish shell either, so it needs to be translated also.

(I have not finished fishifying it yet.)